# Adding SASS to React Project Stalls Yarn Start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, yarnpkg

I'm mid-way though a React project and am now adding styles and implementing SASS, and the other day while I added the packages and some styles, everything was running great. Today I go to boot it up with Yarn Start and and I'm getting:

```
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/hd/zrndmrss6z3cbm68fxxyt4wm0000gn/T/yarn--1553472972241-0.9303472274627695/node but npm is using /Users/kevinhyde/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> test-again@0.1.0 css-watch /Users/kevinhyde/Desktop/CAREER/UW Code Camp/Post_Grad_Apps/test-again
> npm run css-build -- --watch

npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/hd/zrndmrss6z3cbm68fxxyt4wm0000gn/T/yarn--1553472972241-0.9303472274627695/node but npm is using /Users/kevinhyde/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> test-again@0.1.0 css-build /Users/kevinhyde/Desktop/CAREER/UW Code Camp/Post_Grad_Apps/test-again
> node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/mystyles.scss css/mystyles.css "--watch"
```

I have just following packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bulma": "^0.7.4",
    "bulma-extensions": "^6.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-bulma-components": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
```

So far I have tried node re-installs on the related packages and straight up `npm i`, as well as `npm audit` to try to fix, but when I jumped back to the previous branch before adding `node-sass`, all's well. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try deleting node_modules and/or json.lock then re-running `npm i` ?

Comment: Just tried it @benjaminadk . . . no luck so far.

Comment: did you upgrade to that version of node after you originally installed `node-sass` ?

Comment: hm, no i didn't run any node updates in the interim.

Comment: It doesn't say any error, your application break?

Comment: The terminal process just hangs on the lines shown in the post.